# Merging more than two columns of the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Trying to reorganise the below dataframe so that `[VAR]` 1-3 are merged in numeric order along `[GROUP]` column

```
VAR 1   VAR 2   VAR 3   GROUP 
                3   [0-10]
1               3   [0-10]
1               3   [0-10]
1       2           [0-10]
        2           [0-10]
3              3    [10-20]
3       1           [10-20]
        1           [10-20]
        2           [10-20]
               2    [10-20]
               2    [10-20]
```

Trying to get this as the final result:

```
VAR_MERGED  GROUP 
1           [0-10]
1           [0-10]
1           [0-10]
2           [0-10]
2           [0-10]
3           [0-10]
3           [0-10]
3           [0-10]
1           [10-20]
1           [10-20]
2           [10-20]
2           [10-20]
2           [10-20]
3           [10-20]
3           [10-20]
3           [10-20]
```

I've tried to use `df['VAR_MERGED'] = df[['VAR 1' 'VAR 2' 'VAR 3']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)` but get error about expected str, but values in `VAR` columns are all float but not sure why this would need string values?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your real data, please? `df.head(10)` should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> df
    VAR 1  VAR 2  VAR 3    GROUP  ANOTHER
0     NaN    NaN    3.0   [0-10]  another
1     1.0    NaN    3.0   [0-10]  another
2     1.0    NaN    3.0   [0-10]  another
3     1.0    2.0    NaN   [0-10]  another
4     NaN    2.0    NaN   [0-10]  another
5     3.0    NaN    3.0  [10-20]  another
6     3.0    1.0    NaN  [10-20]  another
7     NaN    1.0    NaN  [10-20]  another
8     NaN    2.0    NaN  [10-20]  another
9     NaN    NaN    2.0  [10-20]  another
10    NaN    NaN    2.0  [10-20]  another
```

You can use `melt`. To fully understand, you can execute the code line by line (`df.melt(...)`, `df.melt(...).dropna()`, `df.melt(...).dropna.sort_values(...)` and so on):

```
id_vars = df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('VAR')]

out = df.melt(id_vars, value_name='VAR_MERGED') \
        .dropna() \
        .sort_values(['GROUP', 'VAR_MERGED']) \
        .reset_index(drop=True) \
        [['VAR_MERGED'] + id_vars]
```

Result output:

```
>>> out
    VAR_MERGED    GROUP  ANOTHER
0          1.0   [0-10]  another
1          1.0   [0-10]  another
2          1.0   [0-10]  another
3          2.0   [0-10]  another
4          2.0   [0-10]  another
5          3.0   [0-10]  another
6          3.0   [0-10]  another
7          3.0   [0-10]  another
8          1.0  [10-20]  another
9          1.0  [10-20]  another
10         2.0  [10-20]  another
11         2.0  [10-20]  another
12         2.0  [10-20]  another
13         3.0  [10-20]  another
14         3.0  [10-20]  another
15         3.0  [10-20]  another
```

Comment: Needed to change `int` to `float` for my use but this works, thank you, but I have another column of strings in the df and get `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` how can I deal with this? Works if I exclude this column but I need to keep it unfortunately

Comment: Thanks this works but what if there is another column of strings? How can I add more columns to this

Comment: My variables aren't actually called `VAR`, they all have diff. names so the first line won't work here, what can I put instead?

Comment: When I try this I get `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Answer (score 1):

One way via `set_index` / `stack`:

```
df = (
    df.set_index('GROUP')
    .stack()
    .sort_index(level=[0,1])
    .reset_index(-1,drop=True)
    .reset_index(name = 'Var Merged').iloc[:, ::-1]
)
```

Comment: Swap the columns ;-) +1

Comment: @Corralien Thanks!!.. Updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks this works also but is there a way to add more columns from the df to this?